# Solving a system of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How can I solve a system of polynomial equations like this one 
[image: System of equations]

Maybe I'm missing a very basic trick... Can anybody suggest me an approach?

Comment: What do you get as the product of all those equations? Something symmetric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the reciprocals of each and multiply by $abcdef$ to obtain the equations
$$a^2 = \frac14 abcdef \\ b^2 = \frac19 abcdef \\ \vdots$$

Multiply all original equations to get
$$(abcdef)^4 = 4\cdot 9\cdot 16 \cdots = 1$$

Now you should be able to tell the solution without using a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a logarithm and solve a linear system

\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}
-1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 & -1 &  1 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 & -1 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 & -1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & -1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1&-1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\ln a \\
\ln b \\
\ln c \\
\ln d \\
\ln e \\
\ln f
\end{matrix}\right]
&=\left[\begin{matrix}
\ln 4 \\
\ln 9 \\
\ln 16 \\
-\ln 4 \\
-\ln 9 \\
-\ln 16\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}
\ln a \\
\ln b \\
\ln c \\
\ln d \\
\ln e \\
\ln f
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\tfrac18
\left[\begin{matrix}
-3 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 & -3 &  1 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 & -3 &  1 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 & -3 &  1& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & -3& 1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1&-3
\end{matrix}\right]
{}
\left[\begin{matrix}
\ln 4 \\
\ln 9 \\
\ln 16 \\
-\ln 4 \\
-\ln 9 \\
-\ln 16
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}